# Service Fabric is Removing the ResourceOverrides on Visual Studio build

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

Using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3, Service Fabric SDK 2.7 Runtime 5.7, I am trying to use the ResourceOverrides of the Application Manifest.

I am following the documentation below to create multiple deployment environments:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources

And

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration

Every time I hit the "Run" on my Visual Studio to launch my stateless website, the ResourceOverrides disappears from the manifest (like magic!).

Any idea why I'm getting this? Are you aware of any other way to change the ports binding per deployment environment?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/447